BIG Beginner SQL
Should I make for '이홍근's student sno count
[Search for the number of courses registered by '이홍근]
This is my own
SELECT COUNT (*) AS Number of courses
FROM STUDENT AS S, ENROL AS E
WHERE S.SNO = E. SNO
 AND S.NAME = '이홍근';

Is this right?
I just asked SQL and just need an answer.


The first thing you need to do is read about how to ask a good question on this site i.e. take the tour and then read this [mre].

Then you need to carefully inspect your tags, because you have tagged 2 competing database products... but you should only tag the one you are using.

Then you need to take note of the guidelines that were given to you while you wrote your question. Being not to use images for data, code or errors. Please check the help and format you data as table markdown.

Then you need to make your title reflect the problem you are trying to solve i.e. it needs to say something about wanting to count the number of X from Y. Not that you are a beginner... thats irrelevant to solving the problem.

If you're using Microsoft SQL Server then you need to learn the difference between character literals and National character literals (with the N prefix). Compare the output of SELECT '이홍근', N'이홍근'; on a us-english system to see why this matters.

Three issues:

Number of Courses is not a legal column name. You need to enclose it or remove the spaces.

The A,B join syntax has been obsolete for 30 years, and should no longer be used. Instead of
 FROM STUDENT AS S, ENROL AS E
 WHERE S.SNO = E. SNO AND 
     AND ...

you should write
FROM STUDENT AS S 
INNER JOIN ENROL AS E ON S.SNO = E.SNO
WHERE ...


For SQL Server, you need special handling for string values with non-ASCII characters, so '이홍근' must be  N'이홍근'. MySQL doesn't do this... but that brings up the point that you really ought to know which product you're using. While SQL is standardized, NONE of the products perfectly follow the standard, so it's important to be clear about which product you're using.


